# Bootstrap table-striped from certain rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have my table striped starting from 7th row.

This is not working:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(7n)
```

Comment: Unsufficient info. Please provide your code.

Comment: It's just an ordinary table with <table class="table table-striped">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this

```
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n+7) td {
  background: /* your color here */;
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GMZwZw)

```css
td {
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding:1em;
}

.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background:none !important;
}

.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n+7) {
  background:lightgrey !important;
}

/* note !important is only used here for demo purposes. */

/* This seesm to be because the CSS is applied in the wrong order in Snippets */

/* See the Codepen Demo for use without !important */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This works! But how to set from 1st to 7th row is not striped (I set background on white)?

Comment: This does work but I think the Stack Snippet appllies the CSS in the wrong order. See the Codepen Demo where you have to reset the background color first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use n+7 to do that.

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(n+7) td
```